# STM32F103 timer behaves differently after hardware reset instead of st-flash reset

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer, reset

I'm learning to program the STM32F103C8 Cortex-M3 (on a [BluePill board](https://riot-os.org/api/group__boards__bluepill.html)) and was playing around with the general purpose timers (TIM2 to TIM5) because I wanted to time some routines.

In my simple program I just set up the timer, set TIMx_CNT to 0 and loop until TIMx_CNT exceeds my target delay and blink a LED accordingly, to have a visible output. The relevant code is the following:

```
void setup() {
    /**********************************************************************
     ************************ Set up mcu clock ***************************/
    FLASH->ACR  |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1;     // Set latency to 2 wait states
    RCC->CR     &= ~RCC_CR_HSEBYP;
    RCC->CR     |= RCC_CR_HSEON;            // Enable HSE
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));     // Wait for HSE to be ready

    RCC->CFGR   |= RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;     // HSE as PLL source
    RCC->CFGR   |= RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL10;      // PLL clock multiplier
    RCC->CR     |= RCC_CR_PLLON;            // Enable PLL
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));     // Wait for PLL to be ready
    RCC->CFGR   |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;         // Select PLL as SYSCLK


    /**********************************************************************
     ***************************** Set up GPIO ***************************/
    // GPIOC configuration PC13, PC15
    RCC->APB2ENR    |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
    GPIOC->CRH  = 0x28200000;
    GPIOC->BRR  = 1 << 13;
    GPIOC->BRR  = 1 << 15;

    /**********************************************************************
     ***************************** Set up TIM3 ***************************/
    RCC->APB1ENR    |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;
    TIM3->PSC       |= 1 << 11;               // PSC = 2048
    TIM3->CR1       |= TIM_CR1_CEN;


    /**********************************************************************
     ***************************** Call main() ***************************/
    main();
}

const uint32_t CYCLES = 39062;    // For 1sec on 1sec off blink

void main() {
    while (1) {
        GPIOC->BSRR |= 1 << 13;
        TIM3->CNT = 0;
        while(TIM3->CNT < CYCLES) {}

        GPIOC->BSRR |= 1 << (13 + 16);
        TIM3->CNT = 0;
        while(TIM3->CNT < CYCLES) {}
    }
}
```

To flash the board I am using the [texane stlink utility](https://github.com/texane/stlink).

After I flash the chip, the program runs fine, i.e. the observed blink frequency is the expected 0.5Hz. However if I then push the reset button, the LED no longer blinks (it is PWMing), and checking with the oscilloscope the blink frequency becomes 1kHz. Running the command "st-flash reset" returns everything to normal.

I've tried many things to no avail. I have also printed the TIMx_PSC register to a small GLCD and confirmed that even after the hardware reset the value is still 2048.

Also I know the APB1 bus is overclocked, but running it within spec doesn't change the observed behaviour.

Any help in understanding what is happening is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect your sense of "normal" is actually backwards: the hardware reset button would be the usual case and what you'd probably get on power on, if it is behaving differently after the soft *attempt* at reset, *that* would be the odd case.